# Play 1.2.4 + CRUD Module: Generating hashed passwords

Tags: java, jpa, hash, playframework, crud

I have a user.java class as such

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends Model implements RoleHolder {


   public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Status status, List<UserRole> roles){
    this.email = email;
    this.password = Crypto.passwordHash(password+email);
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.status = status; 
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

And a users.java

```
public class Users extends CRUD {
```

}

However, when I create a user, it stores a plaintext password in the database rather than a salted and hashed one? Any Idea why?

Comment: Does anything (i.e. the "CRUD") set the `password` field *later*? That is, perhaps the constructor isn't the appropriate place to set derived values ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-write `create()` and `save()` method from CRUD class inside `Users` controller class.

Maybe the solution looked like this:

```
@CRUD.For(User.class)
public class Users extends CRUD {
   /**
    * Re-implement Create (C) method
    * @throws Exception
    */
   public static void create() throws Exception {
      // Get model type
      ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
      notFoundIfNull(type); // render not found error if framework can't determine model type
      Constructor<?> constructor = type.entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
      constructor.setAccessible(true);

      // Create new instance of model
      User object = (User) constructor.newInstance();
      // Bind all parameter value from submitted form
      Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "object", object);
      // Hash the password
      object.password = Crypto.passwordHash(object.email + object.password);

      // Check validity of model
      validation.valid(object);
      if (validation.hasErrors()) {
         renderArgs.put("error", play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.hasErrors"));
         try {
            render(request.controller.replace(".", "/") + "/blank.html", type, object);
         } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
            render("CRUD/blank.html", type, object);
         }
      }
      object._save(); // Finally, save the model
      flash.success(play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.created", type.modelName));
      if (params.get("_save") != null) {
         redirect(request.controller + ".list");
      }
      if (params.get("_saveAndAddAnother") != null) {
         redirect(request.controller + ".blank");
      }
      redirect(request.controller + ".show", object._key());
   }

   /**
    * Re-implement Update (U) mehod
    * @param id
    * @throws Exception
    */
   public static void save(String id) throws Exception {
      // Get model type
      ObjectType type = ObjectType.get(getControllerClass());
      notFoundIfNull(type); // render not found error if framework can't determine model type

      // Find the model to be updated
      User object = (User) type.findById(id);
      notFoundIfNull(object); // render not found error if framework can't determine model record
      // Bind all parameter value from submitted form
      Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), "object", object);
      // Hash the password
      object.password = Crypto.passwordHash(object.email + object.password);

      // Check validity of model
      validation.valid(object);
      if (validation.hasErrors()) {
         renderArgs.put("error", play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.hasErrors"));
         try {
            render(request.controller.replace(".", "/") + "/show.html", type, object);
         } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
            render("CRUD/show.html", type, object);
         }
      }
      object._save(); // Finally, save changes
      flash.success(play.i18n.Messages.get("crud.saved", type.modelName));
      if (params.get("_save") != null) {
         redirect(request.controller + ".list");
      }
      redirect(request.controller + ".show", object._key());
   }
}
```